# Sharethis customize whatsapp & facebook messenger text

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, social-media, sharethis

I've implemented the https://sharethis.com/ plugin on my laravel website I am trying to add a text message with the link if chosen to share through facebook or whats app but its not passing through.

I've used these two links for the different fields but nothing appears for them.

https://sharethis.com/support/customization/customize-share-urls/

https://sharethis.com/support/legacy/how-to-customize-which-url-text-and-img-to-share/

The only custom text i've been able to pass through is the data-message attribute for the email content.

Has anyone had any experience when using this plugin and is it possible to provide text alongside the link when sending via whatsapp & facebook messenger?

Comment: For a Facebook share, you are not even _allowed_ to specify the message for the user, they need to type it themselves.

Comment: @CBroe Thanks, is it the same for whatsapp aswell?

Comment: No, for those the text can be specified. (But don't ask me how to do that using ShareThis.)